# Dropwizard [0.9.2] request add Auth information

Tags: logging, jetty, dropwizard

I am trying to add the userId or the username into the http request log, te second field seems to be the one I want to set.

- The remote server address
- *Optional authentication information*
- Request date and time
- The HTTP method, URI, and protocol for the request
- The HTTP response status code
- The length of the response
- The HTTP referer header (if set)
- The HTTP user agent (if set)
- The log latency

reading Jetty source [Jetty source](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/master/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/AbstractNCSARequestLog.java#L131), I found this

```
getUserPrincipal().getName()
```

But I never get the the name of my User. I thnik I am missing something but don't know what.

Some context if it can help

```
public class MyUser implements Principal {
    private Long id;
    private String name;


    public String getName() {
        if (name == null || name.isEmpty())
            return getIdAsString();
        return name;
    }    
    public String getIdAsString() {
        return Long.toString(id, 16);
    }
}
```

Into my ressource

```
@POST
@Path("/test/")

public int test(
        @Auth @ApiParam(hidden = true) Principal user, ...)
{
    logger.error(user.getName());
    [...]
}
```

If I log the `name` with logger I get it with no problem , how to have it into the request log ?

Comment: Which version of Dropwizard are you using? The recent release notes here http://www.dropwizard.io/1.0.2/docs/about/release-notes.html show some problems with the HTTP request logging in 1.0.0 and 1.0.1 versions. And 1.0.2 should resolve them. Issues are #1737, #1678 and  #1415.

Comment: I am using 0.9.2, I have edited my question

Comment: I think [issue #898](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/898) is what you need to check. As mentioned in the comments it seems there is a workaround for this by manually injecting `UserAuthentication` object that Jetty is using for logging requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As advised by zloster  I inject `UserAuthentication` into my `AuthFilter`

```
 Request request = HttpChannel.getCurrentHttpChannel().getRequest();
 if (request != null) {
        Principal user = new Principal() {
            @Override
            public String getName() {
                MyUser user = (MyUser) principal.get();
                return user.getIdAsString();
            }
        };
        UserIdentity userId = new DefaultUserIdentity(null, user, null);
        request.setAuthentication(new UserAuthentication(null, userId));
}
```

Comment: `HttpChannel.getCurrentHttpChannel()` was deprecated, `HttpConnection.getCurrentConnection().getHttpChannel()` is the "new" way to do it